# Get data from a bluetooth laser meter

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am not sure if it is a suitable question for this website.
I want to make an app on **android** that receives data from a bluetooth laser meter.
The "*problem*" I find is that the laser meters I find send all the data to their own predefined applications.
I am looking for a bluetooth laser meter that sends the data reading directly as a string value, float, etc. And that my app is the one that handles the pure data received as needed.

Does anyone know if there is a laser meter that does what I am looking for? Or if they follow a protocol that can be intercepted, etc.?

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You could try to reverse-engineer the protocol. Start with the [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) app from Nordic Semiconductor. If the laser meter uses Bluetooth LE as a peripheral, it will publish the data as GATT characteristics. The app can inspect the device and list the characteristics. Some guessing of the data format will be needed.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349011/connecting-a-laser-distance-measurer-bosch-disto-glm-50-c-with-smartphone-and