# Connecting a Laser Distance Measurer (Bosch C, bluetooth) with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, measurement

Is there a way to connect Laser Distance Measurer with Chrome Bluetooth API. The Bosch devices such as GLM-family have andriod/ios SDK. Im kind of new to this and wondering if there is way to do that, or maybe another companies that offer a javascript SDK for their measurement devices

Comment: There are two parts to your question. 1) Connecting to Bosch GLM (which seems to be covered at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40349011/7721752) . 2) Using the Chrome Bluetooth API (or Web Bluetooth API?) to connect to a BLE device. Once you have the Servce and Characteristics UUIDs from 1, then doing number 2 should be easier.

Comment: The first part (1) is actually my issue. The device has only android/ios SDK and I'm kind of confused how to use those SDK to send data directly to the browser without doing ios/android development

Comment: Use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile). Or if you have Chrome browser on a desktop machine use `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices` to connect to the device and explore. Looks like the service is `00005301-0000-0041-5253-534F46540000`. TX characteristic is: `00004301-0000-0041-5253-534F46540000`. RX characteristic is: `00004302-0000-0041-5253-534F46540000`

Comment: I have access to the Servce and Characteristics with the help of "chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices". But I dont seem to be able  to get any Information regarding the measurement conducted using the device. Sorry for the dumb question but is there like a specific UUID, which I can use to retrive measurements. Does it work like that ?

Comment: There is a Python implementation for MacOS at: https://github.com/piannucci/pymtprotocol/blob/master/protocol.py. The low level python calls will be different than what you want but it might give you some insight in to the commands/bytes/packets to send and receive on which UUIDs